# Maintain TCP Connection in background after opening other application Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, tcp, mqtt

I'm using `MQTT` Server `TCP Connection` to develop my `Chat Application with Image Attachments`.

The `Text Chat` is working `fine` but when comes to `image attachments`,the connection is getting lost and going to `Application_Deactivated` event.

I've tried connecting it back in the `Application_Activated` and `Application_Launching` Event,but even that doesn't work.

Is there any solution to maintain a `TCP connection` throughout the application background without loosing the Connection?

Actually while googling the solution, I came across **Background Agents**,is that going to work for me?If so,Can I get a perfect link for the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you're not going to be able to maintain the TCP session when the user does something to leave your application (whether user backs out of the app or launches some other app).  You should look into an API that the server supports to resume an existing user chat session over a *new* TCP session. I don't know MQTT to provide more specifics on how to achieve this magic.  But once you figure it out, you'll want to use that mechanism to try to resume an *existing* chat session in both your Application_Launching and Application_Activated events.

A BackgroundAgent cannot run more often than every 30 minutes (except when debugging), that isn't frequent enough to keep a TCP session alive.

Comment: But Let's say if I disconnect the Chat and Connect to Albums.If the User receives any Chat,he will not get that ryt?(if Chat is Disconnected)

Comment: I'd say that is expected, desirable behavior.  You'd be "lying" to other users of the chat service by showing your user as present when s/he hadn't been active on your app for more than a few minutes.  On a mobile phone, with its intermittent connectivity, you might stretch this by a few more minutes, but not indefinitely.

Comment: @RealSteel Hi steel, am also faced same issue.But we are reconnecting in app launching and activation, but the problem is to make connection while activation it takes much time to resume the app..Have you faced this one and how have you achieved?..Thanks in adv..